# Exchange 2010 MAPI API PR_HTML couldn't be fetched using 0x10130102 when the mail format is RTF

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

I have an application which fetches email from Exchange groupware. We wanted to fetch the email in HTML format (irrespective if the mail is originally in HTML / RTF format). We used MAPI property PR_HTML (0x10130102) to get the data string. This approach worked fine on all three Exchange groupwares (2003, 2007 and 2010) when the mail is in HTML Format. It worked fine for Exchange 2007 RTF format too. But in case of Exchange 2010 RTF, it returns empty string.

Note: We are retrieving this property as VARIANT and then typecasting the value to char *

We also unsuccessfully tried with other MAPI properties like 0x1013001F (unicode).

Note: One more piece of information is that when we use tools like OutlookSpy or MFC MAPI we could see value in PR_HTML property.

Answer (score 0):

If HTML is not set on the message in question, you will not be able to retreive it.
What is your client version of MAPI? Are you using an online or a cached profile?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, MAPI version used is 1.2.1 and we are using online profile.

Comment: One more point, I thought when we ask for PR_HTML property exchange would return us html converted from RTF. As I could see <meta> converter tag in RTF coming from Exchange 2007.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Exchange performs the conversion when the body is set and the mesage is saved. 1.2.1 is CDO. Are you using the standalone version of MAPI (6.5.X)?